# jdbc consume too much memory

Tags: java, jdbc, memory-leaks

I wrote program in that I need to update 10000. The query is:

```
   for (Ticket ticket : existInBoth) {
        if (!ticket.isUpdatable() && !ticket.isDeleted()) continue;
        String query = String.format("update tickets SET vehicle_id = %d , price = %d , free = %d,time = '%s',date='%s',url='%s',deleted_at=NULL  WHERE unique_key = '%s'",
                ticket.getVehicle().getId(), ticket.getPrice(), ticket.getFree(), ticket.getTime(), ticket.getDate(), ticket.getUrl(), ticket.getUniqueKey());
        if (db.update(query) > 0)
            updatedDates.add(ticket.getDate());    

    }
```

and db.update

```
    @Override
public int update(String sql) {
    synchronized (Main.THREAD_GUARD) {
        int result = -1;
        Connection connection = open();
        try {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            result = statement.executeUpdate(sql);
            statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            close(connection);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

It seems realy easy. But when I ran it I see this updating take about 300MB of memory.

I carefully close all statements and connections.

Comment: I realize that presumably none of those values is free text (or even limited text, probably) from a user, but I still shudder at that. **Please** review http://bobby-tables.com for why.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder my program doesn't interact with users directly therefore it is safe.

Comment: Why don't you use a PreparedStatement to do update batching?

Comment: when do you commit your transaction?

Comment: are you in auto commit mode?

Comment: @rezachess: Doesn't make building SQL statements in strings a good idea. Not least because of the memory churn.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto i test preparedstatment too but nothing change.

Comment: you are in auto commit mode or not?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto i run query each time (that mean in for loop i create query and after that i run it)

Comment: so you are in auto commit mode

Comment: show us your complete code

Comment: @NicolasFilotto i didn't change auto commit mode. it is default

Comment: @NicolasFilotto i edit the question and add complete code